# Eclipse can't create package and instead it creates a folder

Tags: eclipse, package, classpath, directory

**Environment**

- Eclipse Mars 4.5.0

I'm trying to create a package with name *com.javalabs.web.action* but instead of that Eclipse created a folder inside *com.javalabs.web*.
As you can see in the following picture, the icon is not the same that, for example **actions**.
The problem seems to be only with the name action, because a could do that with actions and other names.

I don't care about the package icon, but the big issue is that Eclipse doesn't recognise de classes inside that folder as their classpath.

Any idea of what can be?

[image]

Comment: do you get an error in the error log?

Comment: Have you excluded some folders from the build path?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I didn't realize of that but there it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the "Resource Filters" configured for your project (you can find them as a child of the "Resources" entry in the project properties).

The next set of filters is in the "Java Build Path" where you can configure exclude patterns per source folder.

Comment: I've seen that, but I don't have any

Comment: @Joe: Could be in a parent project/folder

Comment: The problem was that in Java Build Path the tab source had that folder excluded. That's why it couldn't create a package with that name.

Comment: @Joe: I've updated my answer. If you think it now solves your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Click on 'src' folder and refresh. There you go..

Answer (score 1):

That's what I did step by step to solve the problem:

1. Right click on Project Folder > Properties > "Java Build Path"
2. Select source folder where you are creating the package
3. Double click on "Excluded" under the folder you want changes
4. Edit
5. Under Exclusions patterns > remove everything you need to include specially remove the **
6. Finish
7. Apply